# how can I insert a jquery ui spinner when I'm already using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I want to insert a jquery spinner for a number field

```
<input id="spinner" name="number">

<script>
$( "#spinner" ).spinner();
</script>
```

I am already using jquery mobile for other ui options

The way I'm doing it now I'm getting an error message in my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'spinner'
```

Is it even possible to get this working? and how?

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/MaL7b/ Make sure you're using the corresponding jQuery ui version to your jQuery version.

Comment: Use `$.mobile.loading("show")` or hide.